# Trying to Script a Search Result into a Netsuite Entity Field

Tags: field, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

Having two issues with this. One is that I keep getting an error when trying to upload my script. The other is that one version that I did get to upload, didn't load any value into the field (ie. field blank after script ran)

The error I keep getting on upload is "Fail to evaluate script: All SuiteScript API Modules are unavailable while executing your define callback." And although I've made drastic changes to the script, it still won't allow me to upload.

```
 /**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define(['N/search', "N/record"],
 function(search, record) {

function loadAndRunSearch(scriptContext) {
 var mySearch = search.load({
  id: 'customsearch1088'
 });

 mySearch.run().each(function (result) {
  var countt = result.getValue({
   name: 'number'
  });
  var entity = result.getValue({
   name: 'internalid'
  });


 var objRecord = record.load({
  type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
  id: entity,
  isDynamic: true,
 });

  var vfield = objRecord.getField({
      fieldId: 'custentity_orders_12m'
  });
  objRecord.setValue({fieldId: 'custentity_orders_12m', value: countt});
  objRecord.save();
 });
}
  return {
   execute: loadAndRunSearch
  };
});
```

That's the script stripped down to the bare bones (FYI still doesn't upload), and the script that uploaded was basically a more complicated version of the same script, except it didn't set the field value. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't returned the entry function.

```
 /**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define(['N/search', 'N/record'],
function(search, record) {

    function loadAndRunSearch(scriptContext) {
     var mySearch = search.load({
      id: 'customsearch1088'
     });

     mySearch.run().each(function (result) {
      var countt = result.getValue({
       name: 'number'
      });
      var entity = result.getValue({
       name: 'internalid'
      });

      record.submitField({
          type: record.Type.CUSTOMER, 
          id: entity,
          values: {
             'custentity_orders_12m' :countt
          }
        });
     });
    }

    return {
        execute : loadAndRunSearch
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats fine Steve, you've probably hit the cause behind the no value set - only I'm still stuck on the upload issue. Don't know if you've ever come across that error message before?

Comment: That error usually occurs when your code structure is incorrect

Comment: Just changed the above with the edits Steve, looks like that return statement was a carry-over from a previous version sorry - part of the reason for simplifying it was so that incorrect structure might be a bit more obvious... but there's nothing jumping out at me

Comment: It's the entry point call must have "execute" for the SS2.0 script

Comment: Looks like it still doesn't like the "entity" variable - both "setValue" and "submitField" return this error - Error: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: id","stack":["createError(N/error)","<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/ACL/Example4.js:23)","each(N/searchObject)","loadAndRunSearch(/SuiteScripts/ACL/Example4.js:14)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: id"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

Comment: Depends on your type of search

Comment: Hello @Steve Reeder, been offline a bit there - the search is a Transaction search, with two columns, Customers Internal ID grouped, and Document Number Counted

Comment: Your internalid column is the transaction internal id. You need the customer id in your search.  .....getValue({name:'internalid, join:'customer'})

Comment: Add summary:'group' to the get Value as well